# Is it possible to create a simple MacOS Cocoa app with .NET Core?

Tags: cocoa, .net-core

It's currently possible to create C# Cocoa apps on MacOS using [Xamarin.Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/get-started/hello-mac). I'm looking to create a very simple app that opens a window with a web browser inside, without the address bar, and no other controls. Are there any bindings or libraries that can be used from .NET Core instead of Xamarin, to accomplish that?